# CSS position relative acting as absolute

Tags: css, position

I'm having trouble making divs top position be relative to its preceding subling.

I have:

```
<style>
#container {position:absolute; top:0px; height:100%}
.question {position:relative;border: 1px double black;}
.question [scope=title] {position:relative; top:0px; color:black;font-size:28px; border-bottom: 1px double black;}
.question [scope=body] {position:relative; top:0px; color:black;font-size:18px; }
.question [scope=author] {position:relative;top:10px}
.question [scope=tags] {position:relative;top:0px}
</style>
```

and then

```
    <div ID="container">
        <div class="question">
            <div scope="title">A</div>
            <div scope="body">B</div>
            <div scope="author">C</b></div>
            <div scope="tags">D</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I expect author div to be 10px lower than normally would be, and for the following div to be relative to that. However, "tags" and "author" overlap.

So irritating, yet I bet there is a simple answer. Any help?

Comment: You have a bold closing tag in the author div... (?)

Comment: Doesn't affect the CSS, browser compilers will just ignore a loose closing tag.

Comment: That was an error I made while removing code to increase comprehension for you nice people. Silly me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the margin-top on the author instead:

```
.question [scope=author] {position:relative;margin-top:10px}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `question` element is computing to the height of the child elements.
So its height is matching the exact height of the children, but one of the children (C) you are pushing it down 10px so it is overlapping the one below it.

Just change `author` and it will work.

```
.question [scope=author] {position:relative;top:0px}
```

Comment: But I want author to be 10px lower than "vanilla". The question is how do I make following sibling div to be relative to its preceding sibling div?

Comment: Using `padding` or `margin` then.

Answer (score 1):

When one element has a position:relative offset, the element is rendered at an offset, but the other elements are placed in the layout flow as if the element did not have an offset. In other words, the offset happens outside of the layout flow. It's like an absolutely-positioned element that has an invisible placeholder occupying space for it in the layout.

Since you want the elements to respond to one another's offset, that suggests using a different mechanism for offsets, one that happens within the layout flow: padding or margins.